# Resize the web page during selenium automation run to capture a screenshot of whole page

Tags: firefox, selenium, selenium-rc, robotframework

How shall i resize the page during selenium automation run.
I want to capture entire page during a failure not just a visible part of it.
Any leads would be great..

Some more details on what is expected:

**Actual Page Size:**
[image: Actual page which by default opens]
**Expected page Size:**
[image: Expected page size]

Comment: Selenium 3.0 is going back to where it will support nothing more than only "viewport" shots only in all browsers.  In Selenium 2.0, i think only one of the browsers supported it and I dont remember which one.   So, I would give up on this... as there is probably a good reason why the Selenium project couldn't deliver this.

Comment: I am using SeleniumLibrary1... Please check on more details on what is looked for.. Updated with images..

Comment: Are you actually trying to resize the page contents **OR** are you trying to capture whole page in a single screenshot?

Comment: Either of the solutions should be ok.. I just want the entire content of page.. Shrink and then take screen shot or take full length page screenshot.

Comment: Okay. So if you are using **Robot Framework**, which I recommend because it's intuitive and easy, I suggest using `Selenium2Library`, see my answer below. For writing tests I recommend using **Sublime Text** editor + robot framework plugin.

Comment: I updated the answer. Turns out there is a solution for you.

Answer (score 1):

### The built-in `Capture Page Screenshot`

The **Selenium2Library** has a method, which captures whole page in a single screenshot.
This does not work in Chrome however. Tested OK using **Firefox** or **PhantomJS** for headless control.

*Be sure to include the library in settings.*

```
*** Settings ***
Library         Selenium2Library

*** Test Cases ***  #or a keyword, suite setup ,...
Do The Thing
    Open Browser     ${url}    ${BROWSER}
    Maximize Browser Window

    Capture Page Screenshot
```

### The zoom

Possible **workaround for Chrome** could be calling this command.
*This works only in Chrome and IE.*

```
Execute javascript  document.body.style.zoom="30%"
```

#### More reading:

[Selenium2Library:Capture Page Screenshot](http://rtomac.github.io/robotframework-selenium2library/doc/Selenium2Library.html#Capture%20Page%20Screenshot)

* [Selenium 1 vs. Selenium 2](http://code.google.com/p/robotframework-seleniumlibrary/)

Comment: This doesn't solve the problem. OP's browser is already maximized; the problem here is that the contents of the page do not fit into a single screen. Thus the solution would be to either "zoom out" the view before taking the screenshot, or somehow have Selenium to capture the invisible portion of the page as well.

Comment: @E.Z. `Capture Page Screenshot` captures the whole page regardless the position or size of viewport. Have you tried that before downvoting?

Comment: Yes, I'm facing the same problem.

Comment: Hm, I'm afraid this is a difference between how the [SeleniumLibrary](https://code.google.com/p/robotframework-seleniumlibrary/) and the [Selenium2Library](https://github.com/rtomac/robotframework-selenium2library) implement the `Capture Page Screenshot` keyword.

Comment: The SeleniumLibrary (which uses Selenium RC) ends up with a call to [capture_*entire*_page_screenshot_to_string](https://code.google.com/p/robotframework-seleniumlibrary/source/browse/src/SeleniumLibrary/screenshot.py#65).

Comment: The Selenium**2**Library calls [save_screenshot](https://github.com/rtomac/robotframework-selenium2library/blob/master/src/Selenium2Library/keywords/_screenshot.py#L12) which finally uses WebDriver's [get_screenshot_as_file](http://selenium.googlecode.com/git/docs/api/py/_modules/selenium/webdriver/remote/webdriver.html#WebDriver.get_screenshot_as_file) to send a [screenshot](https://code.google.com/p/selenium/wiki/JsonWireProtocol#/session/:sessionId/screenshot) command to the remote WebDriver.

Comment: It looks to me like Selenium WebDriver does not offer a method equivalent to Selenium RC [capture_*entire*_page_screenshot](http://release.seleniumhq.org/selenium-remote-control/1.0-beta-2/doc/dotnet/Selenium.DefaultSelenium.CaptureEntirePageScreenshot.html)

Comment: When using Selenium2Library, there is actually a problem with **Chrome**, which won't capture the whole page. **Firefox** or **PhantomJS** will capture whole page.

Comment: @E.Z. Updated the answer. Hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

My answer will help you understand how you can open the browser window in *different sizes* and also at *different screen position*.

```
driver = webdriver.Firefox()
```

Resize the window to the screen width/height

```
driver.set_window_size(300, 500)
```

Move the window to position x/y

```
driver.set_window_position(200, 200)
```

You can change the screen co-ordinates as per you project requirement. 
As you mentioned in the question you want a screen shot after the error has occurred in your application.
So the best way to implement this is with the try catch exception,

Once try block has failed in catch you can set the size of the window as per requirement and get the screen shot.

Comment: Can the same be shown using the Python Selenium library with robot framework

Comment: What my belief is that the same commands should work for python. Can you try and let me know please?

Answer (score -2):

driver.manage().window().maximize();

Comment: While your answer might be correct, take some time to explain how your code solves the problem, and format the answer at the same time.

Comment: This command just maximize browser window. It does not show full page if page have big vertical length. So this is not accurate answer that questioner want.